# How to check if a UIViewController is of a particular sub-class in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4

I want to be able to check the type of a UIViewController to see if it is of a certain type like this

c code

```
if (typeof(instance1) == customUIViewController) 
{
  customUIViewController test = (customViewController)instance1;

  // do more stuff
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use C code in the iPhone SDK... Have you tried your code yet?

Comment: Except that is not valid C code...

Comment: @dreamlax - I never said it was.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `isKindOfClass:` method indicates whether an object is an instance of given class or an instance of a subclass of that class.

```
if ([instance1 isKindOfClass:[CustomUIViewController class]]) {
    // code
}
```

If you want to check whether an object is an instance of a given class (but not an instance of a subclass of that class), use `isMemberOfClass:` instead.

Answer (score 18):

```
var someVC: UIViewController

if someVC is MyCustomVC {
    //code
}
```

Comment: only this solution was working in my case. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 9):

Swift version:

```
var someVC: UIViewController

if someVC.isKindOfClass(MyCustomVC) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
[vc isKindOfClass:[CustomViewController class]];
```

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to add in addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30304677/4373927) that if you're wanting to see if a view controller is of a certain type in a **switch statement** *(in Swift)* you can do it like this:

```
var someVC: UIViewController?

switch someVC {
    case is ViewController01: break
    case is ViewController02: break
    case is ViewController03: break
    default: break
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.0
in latest, we have to add a self along with the class name
or it will throw an error "**Expected member name or constructor call after type name**"
  the below code u can use for Swift 3 and above

```
  for viewController in viewControllers {
                            if viewController.isKind(of: OurViewController.self){
                                print("yes it is OurViewController")
                                self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                            }
                        }
```