# isKindOfClass method to check Swift ViewController in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

There's this AViewController which is written in Swift. Now in my Obj C manager class I want to check the type of the viewcontroller. But it doesn't read because Obj C read the class name as "ProjectName.AViewController". How can we have the below mentioned check?

```
//Swift class
class AViewController: UIViewController {
}

//Obj C - Manager class
- (void)sampleMethod:(UIViewController *)viewController {
 if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]]) {
  //Action
 }
}
```

Comment: Is `isKindOfClass:` actually failing here? The actual name of the class shouldn't matter, since you're using `[AViewController class]` to check it. the above should work. In my tests, it does.

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, and that is because [AViewController class] is treated as class of type AViewController, where as variable viewController is treated as class of type ProjectName.AViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the bug in swift, @Freerunnering answer will not work.
As a work around, we can get the class name as string and then do the string match.

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([AViewController class] isEqualToString:@"ProjectName.AViewController"]) {
```

}

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about that bug?

Comment: Sure, the compiler couldn't read [viewController isKindOfClass:[SwiftAViewController class]] and hence it'll not compile. I tried cleaning the project and derived data but it wasn't was much help.

Comment: @NickCatib I will have to do some research on that. It looks like a bug to me. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132823/name-of-swift-class-when-exposed-to-objective-c-code-does-not-respect-the-objc?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Add `@objc(...Name...)` before the class name in Swift.

Eg:
Swift

```
//Swift class
@objc(SwiftAViewController)
class AViewController: UIViewController {
}
```

Eg: ObjC

```
//Obj C - Manager class
- (void)sampleMethod:(UIViewController *)viewController {
 if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SwiftAViewController class]]) {
  //Action
 }
}
```

More details: [Name of Swift class when exposed to Objective-C code does not respect the @objc renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132823/name-of-swift-class-when-exposed-to-objective-c-code-does-not-respect-the-objc)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It says "SwiftAViewController" not found.

Comment: The import part is the "@objc(...)" In the swift file. That defines the name the class will have in ObjC.

Comment: If you change it to `@objc(ThingIsAClass) class AViewController: UIViewController` the name it'll have in ObjC is `ThingIsAClass` not `AViewController`.

Comment: Xcode did create SWIFT_CLASS("SwiftAViewController") in "Project-swift.h" class, yet it doesnt read

Comment: Seems to be a bug: Though I presumed they'd fixed it by now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132823/name-of-swift-class-when-exposed-to-objective-c-code-does-not-respect-the-objc?lq=1

Comment: @Freerunnering Joking?

Answer (score -1):

```
let arrControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers

                    for (indx, vc) in (arrControllers?.enumerated())! {
                        if vc is YourViewController{
                            self.navigationController.viewControllers.remove(at: indx)
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code:

```
for viewController in viewControllers {
                            if viewController.isKind(of: OurViewController.self){
                                print("yes it is OurViewController")
                                self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                            }
                        }
```

for more detail you can refer this answer [already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115816/how-to-check-if-a-uiviewcontroller-is-of-a-particular-sub-class-in-objective-c/45858226#45858226)